# Is there any end for async task

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-async

I was working with flutter, when I made http requests with async and Future, when I executed Future.whenComplete() and printed a message, it is printed infinite number of times, can I stop it's execution

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register as many `then`, `whenComplete`, callbacks to a `Future` as you want. They all will be called when the `Future` completes.

If you add such a callback when the `Future` is already completed, the callbacks will be called immediately (in the next microtask as far as I remember).

Comment: `loadStudent().whenComplete(() {
      setState(() {
          debugPrint('a message');
      });
    });`

this is the code, `loadStudent` is a `Future` method when I set the state, it keeps on running for infinite times and prints the message in console infinite times

Comment: If it's inside `build()` it will be called a lot.

Comment: may I know why it gets called lot in build()

Comment: because `build()` usually is called a lot

Comment: The main issue about doing it inside `build` is that you create an endless `setState` loop.